# MySQL failed occasionally

Tags: mysql

I have experienced MySQL server process exits occasionally. THis is annoying as I have to restart the mysql server. Here is the log I found:

```
160409 01:49:44 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
160409  1:49:44 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160409  1:49:44 [Warning] The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--slow-query-log'/'--slow-query-log-file' instead.
160409  1:49:44 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160409  1:49:44 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log) starting as process 26120 ...
160409  1:49:44 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160409  1:49:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160409  1:49:44 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160409  1:49:44 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160409  1:49:44 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160409  1:49:44 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160409  1:49:44 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160409  1:49:44 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
160409  1:49:44  InnoDB: Retrying to lock the first data file
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
```

Comment: Seems like this issue http://serverfault.com/questions/477448/mysql-keeps-crashing-innodb-unable-to-lock-ibdata1-error-11

Comment: An idea: Check that you do not already have another `mysqld` process.

Comment: When do you encounter this error message? At a restart, at a normal start? If a normal start, are you entirely sure there is no mysql service running already? You should check

Answer (score 0):

The error message would lead me to checking exactly that first: You might have multiple MySQL instances running at the same time, possibly spread among multiple users.